# ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore not working in WebApi Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have an API end point which is returning a loop error (as it links a joining class which loops back) so e.g.

```
class A
{
     virtual ClassAB;
}

class B
{
     virtual ClassAB;
}

class AB
{
     virtual ClassA;
     virtual ClassB;
}
```

In an API GET I need to return details of ClassB from the perspective of ClassA (and vice versa in a ClassB GET).

When I get I do the following:

```
IQueryable<ClassA> results = _dbset
    .Include(x => x.ClassAB)
    .Include(x => x.ClassAB.Select(y => y.ClassB))
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(predicate)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ID);
```

So I get the self ref looping error. Now in my DB Context I have:

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

and in my `Global.asax` `protected void Application_Start()` I have:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

However, I am still getting the error; any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you add exception details please. Exception type, message, stack trace, etc.

Comment: @matthew Flynn: What si the exception?

Comment: @Matthew , I was getting the same error, but couldn't find a way to resolve it. As a workaround instead of returning the entire result set, I returned only the required properties as anonymous type from the web api controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;`